# How can I pass url `kwarg` to HyperlinkedIdentityField in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

My `url_conf` looks like follows,

```
...appointments/<slug:company>/ ^service_booking/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$
```

The company part is obtained in the serializer via `context`.

I could have created a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` if the url only had `pk` kwarg as stated in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield). But with added `company` field, I am not able to do that.

Currently, I am using `SerializerMethodField` to handle this issue as follows:

```
def get_url(self, obj):
return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(
        reverse('appointment:service-booking',
                kwargs=dict(company=self.context['company'].id,
                            pk=obj.pk)
                )
    )
```

I believe `HyperlinkedIdentityField` won't have access to context before it is actually passed to the serializer.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to customize the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` in order to provide the extra kwargs:

```
class MyHyperlinkedIdentityField(HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        if hasattr(obj, 'pk') and obj.pk in (None, ''):
            return None

        lookup_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field)
        kwargs = {
            self.lookup_url_kwarg: lookup_value,
            'company': self.context['company'].id,
        }
        return self.reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)
```